# How can I listen to burn or token LP lock events on sol chain

Tags: solana-program, jsonrpc-api, transaction, api, websocket

I have been trying to get onchain events or messages regarding to token LP lock and burns, I have tried using the json rpc api, I listened to the response for hours but i couldn't find any burn or lock event , please can you suggest any solution.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-data-streaming

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.